Converting Columns into Hierarchical Rows
I am trying to convert 4 columns into rows but in hierarchical structure.
Col1        Col2        Col3              Col4
YP HEVEA    YP HEVEA    OTHER CREDITORS   L1220001 - OTHER CREDITORS
YP HEVEA    YP HEVEA    PREPAYMENTS       A1323004 - PREPAYMENTS OTHERS
YP HEVEA    YP HEVEA    PREPAYMENTS       A2349032 - PREPAYMENTS NEW

My request is to convert this into a single column in a tree hierarchy, which looks something like this:
LEVEL     COLUMN
1         YP HEVEA
2         YP HEVEA
3A        OTHER CREDITORS
4A        L1220001 - OTHER CREDITORS
3B        PREPAYMENTS
4B        A1323004 - PREPAYMENTS OTHERS
4B        A2349032 - PREPAYMENTS NEW

I have added a "LEVEL" column just to show the order in which I want it to be, but that is not required in the output. I am trying to use UNPIVOT but am not sure how to implement it.
Here is the test data:
SELECT 'YP HEVEA'                   Col1,
       'YP HEVEA'                   Col2,
       'OTHER CREDITORS'            Col3,
       'L1220001 - OTHER CREDITORS' Col4
FROM   DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'YP HEVEA'                      Col1,
       'YP HEVEA'                      Col2,
       'PREPAYMENTS'                   Col3,
       'A1323004 - PREPAYMENTS OTHERS' Col4
FROM   DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'YP HEVEA'                   Col1,
       'YP HEVEA'                   Col2,
       'PREPAYMENTS'                Col3,
       'A2349032 - PREPAYMENTS NEW' Col4
FROM   DUAL  


Use UNPIVOT to convert the data to a hierarchical data-structure and then use a hierarchical query and use ORDER SIBLINGS BY to generate the required ordering:
WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM   (SELECT t.*, NULL AS root FROM table_name t)
         UNPIVOT(
         (parent, child) FOR depth IN (
           (root, col1) AS 1,
           (col1, col2) AS 2,
           (col2, col3) AS 3,
           (col3, col4) AS 4
         )
       )
)
SELECT child,
       LEVEL
FROM   hierarchy
START WITH parent IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR child = parent
AND    PRIOR depth + 1 = depth
ORDER SIBLINGS BY child

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1, col2, col3, col4) AS
SELECT 'YP HEVEA', 'YP HEVEA', 'OTHER CREDITORS',  'L1220001 - OTHER CREDITORS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'YP HEVEA', 'YP HEVEA', 'PREPAYMENTS', 'A1323004 - PREPAYMENTS OTHERS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'YP HEVEA', 'YP HEVEA', 'PREPAYMENTS', 'A2349032 - PREPAYMENTS NEW' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



CHILD
LEVEL




YP HEVEA
1


YP HEVEA
2


OTHER CREDITORS
3


L1220001 - OTHER CREDITORS
4


PREPAYMENTS
3


A1323004 - PREPAYMENTS OTHERS
4


A2349032 - PREPAYMENTS NEW
4



fiddle

@MTO I just added a new column to the data and it created a chaos. It started repeating rows several times, I assume depends on the number of levels. I tried using distinct and it mess up the order by clause. Can you help with identifying the issue?
https://dbfiddle.uk/TLWG0yGV

@MuhammadAsim You have multiple children linking to multiple identical parents so the hierarchy is going to start branching unless you either remove the duplicates or correlate between depths of the hierarchy. You have not said what output you are expecting but there are several options in this fiddle. However, your question is turning into a similar question to this question.
